# .net - excel to html without excel installed

Tags: .net

i'm creating excel files, by NPOI library from codeplex.
how can i convert this excel files to html? can not call interop and etc.

Comment: This may seem like a silly question but why don't you create the HTML from the same source data you are using to create the Excel file rather than going through a two stage conversion?

Comment: 1. cause i need both of them. first to give people to download xls files, second to watch this files from browser. 2. excel files allready works, so i dont want to create html from begining, just want to convert

Comment: @eba: without knowing more about your specific problem, my guess is that "just convert from excel" actually means *more* work than "just create html from same source", as @Lazarus suggests. Dealing with excel files programmatically to extract data can be a quite challenging task.

Comment: could a workaround be to send this document to google docs?

Comment: seems that this is out of scope of npoi http://npoi.codeplex.com/workitem/8115

Comment: in excel files contains simple tables, but there is a lot of function in cells, so, i get results. if  i will create html it will be long story

Comment: ok. any other libs that in scope?

Comment: If it's ok to bring in a 3rd party component, I can recommend [GemBox](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/GBSpreadsheet.htm). It's a managed library with an API that resembles the Office API a lot (but it's a lot faster). We had it in a project a couple of years ago, and it worked out very well. It's not for free though.

Comment: seems like gembox will not call microsoft automation, and will not create instances of excel on  server?? so it fits to me

Comment: @eba: that is correct; it does not require excel (or any other part of Office) to be installed. That was our case; we had a web app that needed to parse (and create/update) excel files, but were not allowed to have Office installed on the server.

Comment: so i tried it, and it works. create answer or smth, i will plus u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of years ago I was in a project where we had

- the need to parse Excel files
- the need to update and create Excel files (for download)
- an environment that did now allow Excel to be installed on the server

We ended up using [GemBox Spreadsheet](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/GBSpreadsheet.htm), which worked out really well (I think I have recommended it before here on SO). The API corresponds to the API from Office quite well, it's a managed library, and it showed very good performance. It comes with a price tag, but if you are in some sort of commercial project, that might not be a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

For the new Excel formats you can use the [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en). You can then handle all kinds of Office OpenXML files including Excel. For the older .xls format you can use other third party libraries, e.g. OpenOffice.org SDK.