# .net convert excel to html without excel

Tags: .net

sorry for re-asking, but i have new circumstances.
here was my question [.net - excel to html without excel installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828019/net-excel-to-html-without-excel-installed)

and i said that http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/GBSpreadsheetFree.htm fits to me.
but i can not afford it. so, anybody know such libraries but for free?

Comment: Are you working with the latest version of Excel? do you have control on the way excel files are generated in order to target the latest 2010 format or to save as csv?

Comment: i'm working with xls, as in 2003 office

Comment: i'm creating xls files from xls templates, after that, i need to convert this xls to html. xls templates contains many formulas, and creating html from begining, or from xml is not an option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.net - excel to html without excel installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828019/net-excel-to-html-without-excel-installed)

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same question. If the answers you got weren't satisfactory the **edit** your original question with the explanation as to why. This will bump the question and people will be able to take another look.

Comment: sorry, how to delete question?

Comment: There might be a minimum rep requirement but there should be a "delete" link on the same line as the "edit" link under the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using Google Docs?  They can open Excel spreadsheets.